# Ant: i/o-redirection "must not contain the '<' character"

Tags: mysql, ant

I want to integrate an mysql-statement in a build.xml file for ant.

The command should be:

```
mysql -u$user -p$pwd -D$database < app/mysql/geo/data/geo.data.sql
```

For ant, i defined this macro:

```
<macrodef name="populateGeoDatabase">
    <attribute name="user"/>
    <attribute name="password"/>
    <attribute name="database"/>

    <sequential>
        <exec executable="mysql">
            <arg line="-u@{user} -p@{password} -D@{database} < app/mysql/geo/data/geo.data.sql" />
        </exec>
    </sequential>
</macrodef>
```

At first i tried to use multiple `'<arg value>'`-lines for each parameter and also for 
the i/o-redirection to consume the input-sql-file.
Both did not work with the same error message:

```
The value of attribute "line" associated with an element type "arg" must not contain the '<' character.
```

How to achive that "<"-Redirection for ant-exec?

**UPDATE**

As Bhavin Panchani pointed out, i have to escape the "<" with %lt; due to xml-specific markup:

```
        <exec executable="mysql">
            <arg line="-u@{user} -p@{password} -D@{database} &lt; app/mysql/geo/data/geo.data.sql" />
        </exec>
```

But this will also not solve the problem, but result in an running mysql-client stopping with printing all the valid options and variables:

```
 populate-dev-geo-database:
 [exec] mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.43, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.2
 [exec] Copyright (c) 2000, 2015, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
 [exec] 
 [exec] Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
 [exec] affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
 [exec] owners.
 [exec] 
 [exec] Usage: mysql [OPTIONS] [database]
 [exec]   -?, --help          Display this help and exit.
 [exec]   -I, --help          Synonym for -?
 [exec]   --auto-rehash       Enable automatic rehashing. One doesn't need to use
 [exec] Variables (--variable-name=value)

 [exec] and boolean options {FALSE|TRUE}  Value (after reading options)
 [exec] --------------------------------- ----------------------------------------
 [exec] auto-rehash                       TRUE
 [exec] auto-vertical-output              FALSE
```

The only thing i can solve this issue is to use the option "-e" for executing an sql-statement and use then SOURCE. **This works**:

```
        <exec executable="mysql">
            <arg line="-u@{user} -p@{password} -D@{database} -e 'source app/mysql/geo/data/geo.data.sql'" />
        </exec>
```

However, i am still interested in the solution for using i/o redirections with ant in combination with the mysql-client.

Answer (score 3):

you need to escape < according to XML syntax:

```
<exec executable="mysql">
            <arg line="-u@{user} -p@{password} -D@{database} &lt; app/mysql/geo/data/geo.data.sql" />
</exec>
```

Comment: Thank you for this meaningful hint with escape the < to &lt; - Unfortunatly it doesnt solve the problem. MySQL starts then as wrong options would be met. I will update the question to show you what i mean

Answer (score 1):

I/O redirection doesn't work that way - it is something your shell does (at least on Unix).  Use a `<redirector>` in Ant or `<exec>`'s `input` attribute.

Ant's site has a couple of FAQs dedicated to this, see http://ant.apache.org/faq#shell-redirect-1